# Why the state is still showing Promise while using redux? and how should I access the array inside the result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, reactstrap

The state here is showing a promise when I console log the result. How can I access the array inside the promise result I tried Object.key and map but it nothing worked

```
> import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; import {
> useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'; import { fetchStocks }
> from '../Redux/stocks/stockreducer';
> 
> 
> 
> export const Home = () => {
> 
> const dispatch = useDispatch(); useEffect(() =>
> dispatch(fetchStocks),[dispatch]); let result = useSelector((state) =>
> state.stocks); console.log(result)   return (
> 
>     <div>
>      <h1>test</h1>
>     </div>   ); }
```

and this is where I fetch data from API using axios and I thought that by using then I can access the array inside the Promise Object but I cant

```
> import Axios from 'axios';
> 
> const initialState = [];
> 
> export const LOAD_STOCKS = 'GET_STOCKS';
> 
> export const loadAllStocks = (payload) => ({
>     type: LOAD_STOCKS,
>     payload,   });
> 
> export const fetchStocks = (dispatch) => {
>     var options = {
>       method: 'GET',
>       url: 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins',
>       params: {
>         referenceCurrencyUuid: 'yhjMzLPhuIDl',
>         timePeriod: '24h',
>         tiers: '1',
>         orderBy: 'marketCap',
>         orderDirection: 'desc',
>         limit: '50',
>         offset: '0',
>       },
>       headers: {
>         'x-rapidapi-host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
>         'x-rapidapi-key': '03518c50f0mshb2f93a5c3fbb56fp1a5e6ajsn175d3c928506',
>       },
>     };
>     let result = Axios.request(options).then((response) => response.data).then((result) => result.data.coins);
>     dispatch(loadAllStocks(result))
>     return result
>          };
>  
> 
> 
> const Stocksreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
>     switch (action.type) {
>       case LOAD_STOCKS:
>         return action.payload
>       default:
>         return state;
>     }   };
> 
>   export default Stocksreducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `fetchStocks` as a synchronous function, so you are dispatching the return Promise object from the axios request and not the resolved value.

Either dispatch the result value from within the Promise chain:

```
export const fetchStocks = (dispatch) => {
  const options = {
    ...
  };
  Axios.request(options)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then((result) => {
      dispatch(loadAllStocks(result.data.coins));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle any rejected Promises or errors
    });
};
```

Or convert `fetchStocks` to an `async` function and `await` the Promise to resolve.

```
export const fetchStocks = async (dispatch) => {
  const options = {
    ...
  };

  try {
    const response = await Axios.request(options);
    const result = response.data;
    dispatch(loadAllStocks(result.data.coins));
  } catch(error) {
    // handle any rejected Promises or errors
  }
};
```